# Flash Debugger crashes Safari relentlessly

Tags: debugging, flash, safari, crash, flashplayer-10

Ever since Flash Player 10 came out, the debugger version causes what seems like a crash in my browser, either Safari, or Firefox, on Mac OS X. It's been consistently happening with 10.0, 10.1 and 10.2.

And it's not just on the applications I develop. Six or seven times out of ten, when I visit sites like Gamespot with Flash video delivery and a banner ad or two, the debugger kicks out an error and, upon dismissing that error, I can't regain focus of my browser. Clicking a window does nothing but trigger the Mac OS X error sound. I have to force-quit and start again.

The Adobe forums have been no help, and everything else I've seen relative to the debugger crash issues doesn't seem to solve my problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of OS X are you using?

Comment: I have seen this happen to me many times on FF in Windows 7 as well

Comment: File a bug report with adobe? http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa  Also, is there a common theme with the errors?  Is there some kind of load being attempted?  Like Mike I've seen this a lot in FF/Win7 and the error that causes the issue is always a security sandbox violation of some form or another.

Comment: I'm on 10.6.6, but it's been going on since Flash Player 10.0, and so it was happening even before I had Snow Leopard. I don't see any real theme to the errors. They appear to be a bunch of random things that developers didn't clean up in their Flash files that didn't prevent the SWF in question from compiling. They are only errors that debugger picks up. I can surf the same site on a machine that's not running debugger with no problems.

Comment: Happens to me, too.  No way to handle this but to force quit Safari.  Can't say it's an easily repeatable problem, though: When I restart Safari, I can usually load the same site that caused the crash without problems.

Comment: Yeah, while it happens to me on a given site more often than not, it doesn't happen every time. I want to say that if Flash Player throws the error before the page finishes loading, that's when it chokes Safari...but I'm not 100% sure about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this works on a Mac as well, but on a Windows machine, this hack saved me already some time: Often it is just enough to kill the task "plugin-container.exe". This will stop all flash movies immediately and unfreeze your browser. So you can work on without losing all work done in other browser tabs and waiting for your browser to restart.